# error when updating table sql from array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a sql code , this code updating open_list table in hitung column.

```
$hitung=mysql_query("select markers_tujuan.lng,markers_tujuan.lat,open_list.lat, open_list.lng,
((SQRT((((markers_tujuan.lat-markers_tujuan.lng)*(markers_tujuan.lat-markers_tujuan.lng)) + ((open_list.lat-open_list.lng)*(open_list.lat-open_list.lng)))))+(sqrt((((markers_tujuan.lat-open_list.lat)*((markers_tujuan.lat-open_list.lat)))+((markers_tujuan.lng-open_list.lng)*((markers_tujuan.lng-open_list.lng))))))) as hasil
from markers_tujuan, open_list");
$op=mysql_query("select * from open_list");

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($hitung)) {
    //printf ("(%s %s),(%s %s),%s <br> \n", $row["lng"], $row["lat"], $row["lat"], $row["lng"], $row["hasil"]);
    while ($baris=mysql_fetch_assoc($op)){
        //printf ("(%s %s %s %s) <br> \n", $baris["name"], $baris["lat"], $baris["lng"], $baris["hitung"]);

        $try=mysql_query(" UPDATE open_list SET '$baris["hitung"]' = '".$row["hasil"]."' ");
    }
}
```

I`ve been try it but I got an dummy error and I cannot find it . its make me crazy

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)
```

and this is the error line

```
$try=mysql_query(" UPDATE open_list SET '$baris["hitung"]' = '".$row["hasil"]."' ");
```

Comment: The syntax highlighter shows your error: quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your syntax.

The line

```
$try=mysql_query(" UPDATE open_list SET '$baris["hitung"]' = '".$row["hasil"]."' ");
```

Should be:

```
$try=mysql_query(" UPDATE open_list SET '" . $baris["hitung"] . "' = '".$row["hasil"]."' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

$try=mysql_query("UPDATE open_list SET '".$baris["hitung"]." = '".$row["hasil"]."'");